# Member function vs Operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, member-functions

Should i always overload operator if programming language allows to do so, or it's better to create a member function?

For example: 
`bool operator ==(...) {...}` 
or 
`bool equals(...){...}`

Comment: there is no "always" answer here however if the overload operator is intuitive enough, it's generally considered a good overload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an operator maps directly to the meaning of the function, then it's recommended to use the operator, e.g.

- `==` instead of `equals` because it compares equality,
- `+` instead of `add` if it's adding e.g. mathematical vectors,
- but not `+` instead of `add` if it's e.g. appending to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition to other answers:

The main difference between *non member operator==* and *member operator==* or some kind of *equals* method, which comes to my mind, is an opportunity to use implicit conversions when comparing objects of your class/structure.

So, if you have some structure `X`:

```
struct X {
    X() = default;
    X(int) {}
};
```

You might define a *non member operator==* for `X`:

```
bool operator==(const X&, const X&) {
    // some logic here
}
```

And then make use of implicit conversions:

```
X x;
std::cout << (42 == x) << " " << (x == 42) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it only it if it is absolutely clear what it does. For reading code is better to avoid overloading. Because your brain is used to read words and not some operators. And sometimes operators could do something different what you would guess. But I thing that `==` is clear enough.

Operators are good to use if they are used as callbacks in some libraries. e.g. `std::sort`. You can define your `operator <` which will be used and it will define how to sort your objects.